# TypeError: form.ClientSideValidations.settings is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, client-side-validation

I am using client side validation
https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations
in my aplication.Every thing seems fine but  I am getting  following error...

> > TypeError: form.ClientSideValidations.settings is undefined
> >     return $(this).isValid(form.ClientSideValidations.settings.validators);

i dont know how to get rid from this plz help me

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue?